# Does temporarily quitting singing lessons affect your voice

Tags: theory, voice, performing, lessons, vocal-cords

I have been taking singing lessons for 9 months, but I will have to stop for about 3 to 4 months because I will be moving to another state for some reasons. Will this cause my voice to get worse, and if so, how can I prevent this from happening and improve my singing during this time?

Is it common for singers to stop taking voice lessons for a while or permanently and still having good singing voice and making good songs?  I'm not talking about full-time professional singers like Ariana Grande, Beyonce, or Adele. I'm referring to the good independent singers who have a good voice and make good songs as a hobby or interest yet are still good at it.

Comment: As  long as you keep on singing in between times, to keep the voice going, it should be no problem.. If you, for any reason, don't sing at all between, then, yes, there will be degradation. Why wouldn't there be?

Comment: Yeah it’s not the lessons, it’s the practice that’s important.

Comment: Occasionally you voice will even get better if you take a break, as it will have time to rest and regenerate from potential stress. If you stop taking lessons for some time the only thing that would really happen is you having less progress, unless you tend to do harmful things while singing on your own.

Comment: Singing uses many muscles: diaphragm, chest, throat, and mouth — and while everyday life uses most of them, it won't exercise them in the same way that singing does. So going for some time without singing is likely to cause some of them to lose tone. The effects could include loss of fine control, reduction in range, loss of support, etc. But of course none of that is permanent: it'll come back when you start practising again (and probably much quicker, now you know what to do).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your teacher. If your current teacher is bad, then it could actually be good to stop taking lessons!

Beyond that, it depends on a lot of different factors.

Beginner singers usually have lots of bad vocal habits (straining to hit high notes, poor breath management). Good teachers help beginners to fix these bad habits. Beginners will often revert back to their bad habits if they stop taking lessons.

Advanced singers may have mastered the fundamentals enough that they won't benefit as much from regular singing lessons: they can detect and fix singing issues on their own.

In terms of trying to improve your singing without lessons: just keep practicing your singing, and don't push through pain. The biggest risk is that your technique is bad, and you don't have a teacher to correct it. If your voice doesn't feel good, then take a break.

You can also seek out alternative sources of feedback besides lessons. Example: post a video of your singing online and ask for feedback

There are thousands of "good, independent singers", and they have a wide variety of approaches to getting singing lessons. There are lots of good singers who take weekly lessons, as well as other good singers who never take lessons.